# Blender 2.8 create viewport similar to startup user perspective

Tags: 3d-view

In CAD programs there are usually standard viewports that have buttons so as to find or easily return to a viewport. When you start a new blender file, it opens up in a somewhat isometric view of a cube. I am trying to return to this view or recreate it with an easy way to return to it as a default reference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly...
Start blender with no file loaded.
Arrange your viewport.
Then click on File->Defaults->Save Startup File

To return to certain viewport setups while working with blender try the following addon (here: Blender 2.80):
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would that help me to have a default viewport that I can return to at any time during the design process?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I understood you wanted a certain viewport for any new start. I edited my previous answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. I don't think Blender is for me as I'm very much used to regular CAD standards without addons and maintenance overhead.